# Как создать проект в NetBeans из существующих файлов .c, .h, Makefile и build.sh?

Tags: c++, netbeans, проект

Есть файлы .c и .h формата, которые компилируются запуском build.sh.
Содержание Makefile:

> clean:
>
> -rm *.o
>
> -rm xorfilter

и build.sh

> echo compiling...
>
> make clean
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c -o xorfilter.o xorfilter.c
> -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c -o queue.o queue.c -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c -o filter.o filter.c -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c -o xorencrypt.o xorencrypt.c -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c -o checksum.o checksum.c -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> g++ -g -W -Wall -o xorfilter xorfilter.o queue.o filter.o xorencrypt.o
> checksum.o -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
>
> echo done.

Как создать из этого всего проект в NetBeans IDE 8.0.2? Самое главное, чтобы остались -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue. Иначе работать программа не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил попробовать в Qt Creator создать проект. Добавил в .pro файл опцию LIBS += -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Создать именно с этими файлами вряд ли получиться но можно в обычном проэете зайти в **свойства** -> **Компилятор C++** и в разделе **Строка компиляции** -> **Дополнительные параметры** указать:

> -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue

Comment: Просто создать проект с пустыми .c, .h файлами, скопировать туда код и добавить в параметры компилятора эти параметры эти не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь нужно отказаться от "проекта Netbeans" и использовать отдельную систему сборки. Дело в том, что в случае, если вы используете встроенные средства IDE, то вы очень сильно на нее завязываетесь, чем ограничиваете переносимость своих проектов. К примеру, я не использую NetBeans в разработке, и не смогу собрать ваш проект.

В простейшем случае, вам нужно переписать ваш build.sh на Makefile, и [импортировать](https://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html#ExistingMakefile) его в NetBeans.

Я не спечиалсит по Makefile, и предпочитаю использотвать более продвинутые системы сборки, но для вашего проекта можно использовать, например, [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484873/774651) Makefile

```
TARGET = xorfilter
LIBS = -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -g -W -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused -c

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Попробую. Могу и на другом IDE попробовать. Просто я смог только Netbeans установить. Непросто устанавливать IDE в линуксе.

Comment: Как это - непросто? Проще не бывает: `sudo apt-get install что-нужно`, всё.